# explain the functioning of memset(arr, 10, n*sizeof(arr[0]))?

Tags: memset

I call this function:

```
memset(arr, 10, n*sizeof(arr[0]))
```

I have this output:

```
168430090 168430090 168430090 168430090 168430090 168430090 168430090 168430090 168430090 168430090
```

Why?

Comment: Please speak english

Answer (score 1):

`memset` fills memory with  *8-bit* values but the elements of your array are *32-bit* values. `10` in hex is `0A` so each value in your array becomes `0x0A0A0A0A` which when converted to decimal is `168430090`.